# Ipython output delayed in multiple threading case

Tags: multithreading, ipython

The following code gives unexpected result with IPython:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from threading import Lock

def checkinput(anwser):
    ilock.acquire()
    testVar = raw_input("Input {0}:".format(anwser))
    result='right' if anwser==testVar else 'wrong'
    print(result)
    ilock.release()
    return result

answerList=['a','b','c']

ilock=Lock()
pool=ThreadPool(2)
reslist=pool.map(checkinput, answerList)
```

The output in IPython:

```
Input a:a
Input b:b
Input c:c
right
right
right
```

I was expecting result like this:

```
Input a:a
right
Input b:b
right
Input c:c
right
```

Is it possible to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to flush stdout after print ? `sys.stdout.flush()`

Comment: Flush does not work here.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around by replacing 'display' to 'print'.
However this is weird to me, open for better solution.

display shows single quotes:

```
Input a:a
'right'
Input b:b
'right'
Input c:c
'right'
```